# *(*ptr)[4] and ++(*ptr)[2] functionality in this program

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i;
    const char *arr[] = {"C", "C++", "Java", "VBA"};
    const char *(*ptr)[4] = &arr;
    cout << ++(*ptr)[2];
    return 0;
}
```

Output is "ava"

I am not able to understand why code is giving this output.
I tried to breakdown the code line by line to understand, but I am not that good in pointers so I am not able to understand what *(*ptr)[4] and ++(*ptr) is doing?
So I want to know their functionality in this code

Comment: `const char *(*ptr)[4]` is a variable declaration. See if you can unwind what it is a declaration of.

Comment: According to the [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), the declaration of `ptr` is "`ptr` is a pointer to an array of four elements, each element is a `const char *`. The initialization of `ptr` makes it point to the array `arr`. When you dereference `ptr` (iwht `*ptr`) you get the "value" that it points to, in this case the array `arr`. So `(*ptr)[2]` is equivalent to `arr[2]`. And the increment operator works as usual.

Comment: _" I am not able to understand what ... ++(*ptr) is doing?"_  You are mentally-unwinding that expression incorrectly.  It's `++(*ptr)[2]`.  You are not able to understand what `(*ptr)[2]` is (it's a pointer to `"Java"`), and what it means to increment _that_.

Comment: Relax, you are not going to need this. At a code review this would just be rejected with a "What the f-ck?". You are not supposed to be juggling while standing on one leg, you are supposed to write **readable** code..

Answer (score 4):

Lets look at different statements in your program.

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement:

```
 const char *arr[] = {"C", "C++", "Java", "VBA"};
```

The above statement creates an *array named `arr` that contains elements of type `const char*`.* The size of this array is 4.

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statement:

```
const char *(*ptr)[4] = &arr;
```

The above statement creates a *pointer named `ptr` that points to an array of size 4 that contains elements of type `const char*`*. Moreover, this pointer `ptr` is initialized with `&arr`. This means, the pointer `ptr` is pointing to the array `arr`.

Since `arr` is of type `const char* [4]` therefore , `&arr` gives us a `const char* (*)[4]`.

##### Case 3

Here we consider the statement:

```
cout << ++(*ptr)[2];
```

In the above statement, `(*ptr)` **dereferences** the pointer named `ptr`. This gives us the object to which `ptr` was pointing. But we know that(from case 2) `ptr` is pointing to the array `arr`. So the result of `(*ptr)` is nothing but the array named `arr`.

Now, the operator `[]` has [**higher precedence**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than operator `++`. This means that the array `arr` that we got as a result of dereferencing, is **subscripted** for the value `2`. That is we now get the 3rd element(which is at index `2`) of the array `arr`. This means we now have a pointer that is pointing to the first element/character of the string literal `"Java"`.

Finally, that pointer value is incremented. This is because of the `++`. This mean now after incrementing, the pointer is pointing to the next character(which is `'a'`) in the string literal `"Java"`.

So when you use `cout` on this pointer you get `ava` as the output because the pointer was pointing to the character `'a'` and not `'J'`.

Answer (score 2):

1. First line:

   ```
   const char *(*ptr)[4] = &arr;
   ```

   This declares `ptr` to be a pointer to an array of 4 pointers to const char, and initialize it to point to `arr`
2. second one (I willingly omitted the `cout`):

   ```
    ++(*ptr)[2];
   ```

   This increments the third element of the array pointed to by `ptr`, hence `arr`. After that, printing elements of the array would give `C`, `C++`, `ava` and `VBA`.

Comment: Thanks buddy, understood it